# How to detect if `-Wdev` was passed to CMake?

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to detect if `-Wdev` was passed to CMake from within a CMakeLists.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `-Wdev` or `-Wno-dev` options are passed to `cmake.exe` the user's choice is persisted in the `CMAKE_SUPPRESS_DEVELOPER_WARNINGS` cached variable (see [cmake.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmake.cxx#L1317)). But be aware that the variable is not there, if no `-W` option is given.

I've done some testing and e.g. with **`-Wdev`** command line option I see the following lines added to my `CMakeCache.txt`:

```
//Suppress Warnings that are meant for the author of the CMakeLists.txt
// files.
CMAKE_SUPPRESS_DEVELOPER_WARNINGS:INTERNAL=FALSE
```

So you can check for this variable and see if it's set to `FALSE` with:

```
if (DEFINED CMAKE_SUPPRESS_DEVELOPER_WARNINGS AND 
    NOT CMAKE_SUPPRESS_DEVELOPER_WARNINGS)
```